# Flutter multi-column display, just like the css3 columns

Tags: flutter

I want to make a novel reader, but the length of the text can not be determined, what are some way to split text into different pages? Just like CSS clomuns layout.

Answer (score 0):

[Wrap widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) sounds like what you're looking for.